# Need help changing font size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help changing the font size in this HTML code. It was done in Javascript and I have no coding background. I wouldn't even bother with it, but my client insist on having the countdown on her album website.

```
<div class="countdown">
<script language="JavaScript">

                    TargetDate = "11/20/2013 12:00 AM";
        BackColor = "transparent";
        ForeColor = "ccc";
        CountActive = true;
        CountStepper = -1;
        LeadingZero = true;
        DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days / %%H%% Hours / %%M%% Minutes / %%S%% Seconds";
        FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
   </script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.themepenguin.com/files/theme/countdown.js"></script>
</div>

<div style='display:none'>{menu}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but "questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". Please make some attempt to research first.

Comment: What is your field of work that requires working with sites without knowledge of JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css"> .countdown { font-size: 11px; } </style>
```

Comment: This invalid javascript. Maybe some explanation would be nice (also, please don't answer questions that don't show any effort)

Comment: This is not JavaScript, it's CSS (the proper way to handle fonts).

Comment: Invalid JavaScript? Or just not JavaScript at all. This is this users first (and probably last) question and it sounds like he is just trying to change the font of his countdown. CSS is the proper way to do this.